# How to do database migration Rails3 + datamapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datamapper, rails-migrations

I used dm-rails gem that allows datamapper to hook into rails-3 ,generated a scaffold and a migration file ,did rake db:migrate for database migration but nothing happens no error no migration, can any one suggest me how to run migrations with datamapper and rails-3.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get [dm-rails](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-rails) that add among other things, 2 specific rake tasks:

> rake db:automigrate

it performs destructive automigration, so it checks if table exists, and if so then drop it, and create one more time.
and

> rake db:autoupgrade

It's upgrade your database schema to match your model properties.

Comment: `rake db:autoupgrade` is non destructive to, it's just like running `Datamapper.auto_upgrade!` But the railsy way.